How to modify the wp_query search criteria for modifying tag pages in WordPress themes
I need to display the search results of keyword search based on tag names on the tag page of the topic, so I used method one:
Add the following content to tag.php:
$tagName = single_tag_title('',false);
$args = array(
's' => $tagName,
'order' => 'DESC',
'orderby' => 'relevance',
'paged' => $wp_query->query['paged'],
);
$wp_query->set( 's', $tagName );
$wp_query->set( 'tag', '' );
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

At the same time, modify the have_posts() and other characters in tag.php to $wp_query ->have_posts().
At this point, the current page can display custom query results, but when flipping to the second page, the template jumps to page 404. (Because the tag is not associated with the article)
To solve the problem encountered in method one, I modified the code and added the following code to function.php:
function set_page_tagname( $query ) {
    if ( is_tag() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $tagName = single_tag_title('',false);
        $query->set( 's', $tagName );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'set_page_tagname' );

But the code doesn't work after being added, and I can't see any parameter changes when I print print_r ($wp_query ->query) in tag.php. I don't know how to modify it.
